# Add loop Number via javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and want to create a function which will add numbers through loop. Suppose, I am willing to add 3 to 100 like 3+4+5+6+.......+100
Can you please help me to understand the very basic concept via function ?

```
function addNum(num1,num2){
 var num;
 var sum = 0;
 for(var i = num1; i<= num2; i++ ){
  num = i;
  sum += num;
 }
}
console.log(addNum(1,2));
```

It shows me undefined. Please explain me the error also. Thanks

Comment: your function needs a return statement at the end, otherwise it will return undefined. So: `return sum;`

Comment: What is the best way to create such function ?

Comment: This particular calculation does not need a loop, it can be derived mathematically. `return num2*(num2+1)/2 - num1*(num1-1)/2;`

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return` the sum

```js
function addNum(num1, num2) {
  var num;
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
    num = i;
    sum += num;
  }
  return sum; //returning the result
}
console.log(addNum(2, 3));
```

Comment: You mean return?

Comment: @jas7457 yes. Apologies for the mistake.Have edited it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:-** 
**Starts from 0**

```
function loopit(start_val,end_val){
var i;
var sum = start_val;
    for(i=start_val;i<=end_val;i++){
  sum += i;

  }
  return sum;
}

alert(loopit(0,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why undefined is being returned has already been answered so I will skip that and instead answer the concept of what you are trying to do.

The `for` loop takes 3 parameters. The first, `i = num1` is your staring point, so `i` is equal to whatever number is passed into your function as `num1`.

The second, `i <= num2` tells the loop to continue running until `i` is less than or equal to (`<=`) `num2`, the second parameter being passed into your function.

The third, `i++`, means on each iteration of the loop, add 1 to `i`.

When you put the 3 parameters together, it starts to make sense. If `num1` is 1 and `num2` is 10, and you've said on each iteration increase by 1, your loop will run 10 times (until `i` is no longer less than or equal to 10).

Within the loop itself, you are saying `num = i`. On each iteration of the loop, `i` increases (because remember the 3rd parameter of the loop). So you store `i` within the num variable and in the next line you use `sum += num`. `+=` means take whatever is already in `sum` and add `num` to it. So each iteration of the loop, you are adding `i` (as `i` is increasing you are saying 1+2+3...).

You could actually remove the `num = i` line and change the following line to `sum += i`.

Hope this helps summarise a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it that way, there is a ready arithmetic formula.

```
 sum = (max−min+1)(min+max) / 2
```

In order to do it using javascript code, please refer the below code.

```js
    function sum(min,max){
             return (max-min+1) * (min + max) / 2;
    }
    alert(sum(2,3))
```